# How to fit a Black-Scholes Option Pricing curve with data?

Tags: r

How to use nls with this function and my data to fit a curve?
I expect the output gives the estimated parameters involved in the black-scholes pricing function.

```
m.1 <- nls(MVBV ~ BSOption(EBV,K), 
           data = df_treated[df_treated$FYear==1997 & df_treated$EBV > 0 ,], 
           start = list( K = 0.1), trace = T) 

BSOption <- function(CallPutFlag, S, X, Time, r, sigma) { 
  d1 <- (log(S/X)+(r+sigma^2/2)*Time)/sigmasqrt(Time) 
  d2 <- d1 - sigma * sqrt(Time)
  if(CallPutFlag == 'c') { 
    P <- Spnorm(d1) - Xexp(-rTime)*pnorm(d2) 
  } else { 
    P <- -Spnorm(-d1) + Xexp(-r*Time)*pnorm(-d2) 
  } 
  P 
}
```

Comment: m.1 <- nls(MVBV ~ BSOption(EBV,K), data = df_treated[df_treated$FYear==1997 & df_treated$EBV > 0 ,], 
           start = list( K = 0.1), trace = T)

BSOption <- function(CallPutFlag, S, X, Time, r, sigma) {
  
  d1 <- (log(S/X)+(r+sigma^2/2)*Time)/sigma*sqrt(Time)
  d2 <- d1 - sigma * sqrt(Time)
  
  if(CallPutFlag == 'c') {
    P <- S*pnorm(d1) - X*exp(-r*Time)*pnorm(d2)
  } else {
    P <- -S*pnorm(-d1) + X*exp(-r*Time)*pnorm(-d2)
  }
  P
}

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question to include this code, where it can be formatted and read more easily. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: I've edited your question to include a formatted version of the code from your comment